# Append new item to LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create something like editable UITableView on iPhone.

[image]

I added a button to add new items at the end of the list which would be the equivalent of the "+" button on iphone, this takes user to a list of items to add. My problem is that when they select one I don't know how to add it to the list.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:key="application_preferences"
            android:title="Applications">
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I append a view inside the LinearLayout programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) to add a child view to a `ViewGroup`, but also consider just using [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: thanks, I was actually working on a PreferenceScreen, I wrote LinearLayout because I thought it would be a more common scenario. Can I use a Listview inside the preference screen?

Comment: I haven't played with the Preference-related APIs much in Android, but from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html#bind%28android.widget.ListView%29) it sure seems like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but if you try to add a view to the linear layout programmatically just use `Layout Inflater`

```
LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService("layout_inflater");
 View myView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
 final LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutID);
 ll.addView(myView);
```